# Dockerize .net app with nested solution file

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, solution

I want to dockerize multi-project solution with nested solution file. This is what I tried to do:

Folder structure:

```
-Project1
--project1.csproj
-Project2
--project2.csproj
-ProjectApi
--DockerFile
--projectApi.sln
--projectApi.csproj
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectApi.csproj", "."]
COPY ["../Project1/Project1.csproj", "../Project1/"]
COPY ["../Project2/Project2.csproj", "../Project2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ProjectApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ProjectApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectApi.dll"]
```

My jenkins configuration:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q) || true
sh stop_containers.sh || true

docker build --no-cache -t project_server_api -f ./project_Api/Dockerfile .
docker run -d --log-opt max-size=5m --log-opt max-file=3 --name projectApi
cd ..
```

Error I get:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder193332682/ProjectApi.csproj: no such file or directory
```

I tried with different paths or dockerfile in upper folder but I've got:
`Forbidden path outside the build context`
What should I change?

Comment: you missed copying sln file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move up a directory like you do with the source file in `COPY ["../Project1/Project1.csproj", "../Project1/"]`.

That takes you outside the build context and that's not allowed for security reasons.

You need to move your Dockerfile up a directory and adjust the paths in the Dockerfile. That way all the files you want to copy are in the same directory as the Dockerfile or in directories below that.

Here's my guess at how your Dockerfile should look based on your directory structure

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj", "ProjectApi/"]
COPY ["Project1/Project1.csproj", "Project1/"]
COPY ["Project2/Project2.csproj", "Project2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectApi.dll"]
```

For simplicity's sake, it's nice to have the Dockerfile in the directory that is also the build context, so you might consider moving the Dockerfile up one directory.

Comment: Also, need to put the docker file into the same location as the sln file

Comment: @samnaction The solution file isn't used for anything in this Dockerfile, since OP builds the csproj file.

Comment: Doesnt this ```-f ./project_Api/Dockerfile .``` open nested dockerfiled but leaves context in upper folder?

Comment: @Gohini Yes, your build context is the current directory in that case. So your COPY statements should look something like `COPY ["Project1/Project1.csproj", "Project1/"]`.

Comment: @Gohini I updated my answer with the changes needed to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great.
One issue: I needed to change 
```RUN dotnet restore "ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj"``` to ```RUN dotnet restore "ProjectApi.csproj"``` because there was an error that it could not find that file. But now there are errors from that restore: 
```Skipping project "/Project1/Project1.csproj" because it was not found.```
Is there a way to fix it?
It continues to build with success, also it is later restoring in RUN dotnet build and RUN dotnet publish.

Comment: In the ProjectApi.csproj file, there are references to the other project files. You need to make sure that the paths in there are correct. Since it works on your machine outside the container, it's probably an error during the copying into the image, where the files don't get placed correctly. I'm a little confused that you say that you needed to remove the directory on the restore command. That would indicate that ProjectApi.csproj is in the /src directory and not in /src/ProjectApi like it should be.

Comment: Ok, I made stupid mistake, I left ```COPY ["ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj", "."]``` instead of ```COPY ["ProjectApi/ProjectApi.csproj", "ProjectApi/"]```
Thank you very much, it works great.

Comment: @Gohini Great! If you would mark the answer as accepted, that would be nice.